# How to retrieve query parameter value while using Apache Camel?

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, spring-camel, apache-camel-3

I have a REST endpoint http://localhost:8080/replaymessages/{messageids} wherein messageids will have comma (,) separated values - say 123,456,789 and so on. How to retrieve these values while using Apache Camel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *bean* to invoke a static method like *org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.split* to split the path param stored in the header:

```
rest()
    .get("/replaymessages/{messageids}")
    .to("direct:processMessageIds");

from("direct:processMessageIds")
    .bean(StringUtils.class, "split(${header.messageids}, ',' , -1)")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "id[0] == ${body[0]}");
```